# Error activating IFilterProvider using binding from IFilterProvider to NinjectFilterProvider

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-4.0, ninject

I'm getting this error in production on a project using Ninject 3.2 and .NET Framework 4

```
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services
```

Initially I have checked for constructors which reference another classes whose constructors are dependent upon the first constructor, basically trying to identify a circular dependency, to no avail. The error message doesn't specify the affected class(es)
Would like to know other areas to check for.

**StackTrace:**

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ActivationException 
    Exception message: Error activating IFilterProvider using binding from IFilterProvider to NinjectFilterProvider
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Activation path:
  1) Request for IFilterProvider

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for IFilterProvider on any implementations of the service.
  2) Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
  3) Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
     if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected.

   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__95`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__59`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__75`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviderCollection.<RemoveDuplicates>d__b.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__75`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Mvc.FilterInfo..ctor(IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Is there a Stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace added